# unresolved external symbol "bool ros::console::g_initialized"

Tags: ros, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm creating a small package in Windows using the Msvc Build Environment - Fuerte. I have run the sdk demo and it executes very well. But when I have wrote my own application and I try to compile it, the linker throws me the error:
unresolved external symbol "bool ros::console::g_initialized"

I have checked the include folder and the lib folder and the rosconsole.lib but I can't produce the executable. I have looking for the g_initiaized variable but I only found the extern definition. I can't found the real declaration.

Any help will be useful,

Alxperez

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37896/unresolved-external-symbol-%22bool-ros::console::g_initialized%22/) by [aperez](https://answers.ros.org/users/423/aperez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I answer my own question. You need to include the ROS_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS definition in order to uses the dlls instead of the static libraries.

I have generated the msvc project using a catkinized cmake inside the console2. This project doesn't have some configurations like folder include (rosdeps), or some  additional preprocessor definitions like BOOST_LIB_TOOLSET="vc" in order to correctly find the boost libraries and the ROS_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS definition that uses the dlls.

Once this definitions is added, and the rosdep folder is included, the program compiles and links very well.

---

Originally posted by [aperez](https://answers.ros.org/users/423/aperez/) with karma: 26 on 2012-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1